# Adding mode picture in picture in expo

Tags: expo, picture-in-picture

i have a problem. I need to add the mode picture in picture in android. I use expo (react) but i don't find the library for insert it. Somebody could help me please?

Answer (score 0):

There is no mention nor reference of any similar API for Picture-In-Picture (PIP) in the Expo docs yet.

If you still want to use PIP, you will need to [eject](https://docs.expo.dev/archived/expo-cli/#expo-eject) your project. Then you will be able to install CocoaPods and then [react-native-video](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/blob/master/API.md#installation).